# Secure boot (Ubuntu) disable via UEFI not possible - what to do?

Tags: ubuntu, boot, uefi

Short history:

I have a brand new Acer Aspire 5 (A515-45G-R3YL) 15,6" Full HD IPS, Ryzen 7 5700U, 16GB RAM, 1000GB SSD, Radeon RX640, Linux
I installed Ubuntu, latest version.

Now I wanted to change this installation to Kali linux but the system give safe boot failure.

Problem:

Thus I tried to disable the safe boot option through the UEFI settings but the only thing in that part of the menu I can change is the boot order.

I searched the web and this forum but could not find a solution on how to disable secure boot if the UEFI menu does not provide it

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this uses the same InsydeH20 Setup Utility as some other Acer laptops, you need to first setup Supervisor password. After that you can disable Safe Boot under the Boot -section.

I'd recommend that before installing Kali you should go through the documentation, just so that you know exactly what you're getting into. Repeated ad nauseam... but it's not intended to be used as a desktop distro. If you don't know it, it might be an idea worth considering to first download their [ready-made Virtual Machine](https://www.kali.org/get-kali/#kali-virtual-machines) to get a bit more familiar with it before installing it on actual hardware.

Comment: Just out of curiosity:
I do already have Kali installed on a mini desktop PC, funny enough.
But why is it recommended for desktops?

Comment: I take it you mean "not recommended" :-D It's a toolset targeted for pentesters and other security professionals. To make it fit the purpose the devs have disabled or entirely removed services, libraries and tools that are available on any desktop. It's also a rolling distro, which are inherently more unstable than regular desktop distros. Even professionals who have used it for a decade are known to be facing surprises. Using it for desktop is a bit like preparing rice in a watercooker... it can be done but it's not necessarily the most efficient or convenient way :-)

Comment: Check the page and documentation, they do explain things pretty well there :-) Or just search for Kali in Unix&Linux, SuperUser and StackOverflow - some of the stories are just hilarious :-D

Comment: Don’t forget: https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5360/22222